# Caret "NA not permitted in predictors" when I have no NAs

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I am using caret to train a random forest like so:

```
rf <- train(x = x.train,
y=y.train, method = "rf", ntree = 100, tuneGrid = expand.grid(mtry = c(3,5,10), trControl = ctrl)
```

I am using LGOCV as ctrl, where I withhold 75% of the training data as validation set. However, for this specific choice of validation data I am getting the error "NA not permitted in predictors". As other threads have already mentioned, I checked that I do not have NAs in one of my predictors. Furthermore, when I decrease the size of the validation set to say 71%, the algorithm works just fine. I cannot provide you with a reproducible example as the data is covered behind an NDA, but there might be someone out there who experienced a similar weird behavior.

The error seems to be caused by trControl, as I am able to fit the model when I change the validation size, but I do not understand why this is the case as there are no NAs anywhere in my data.

Maybe important note: This is not exclusive to the random forest, but also applys to other tree-based methods. However, I can fit a linear model.

Comment: This question cries out loudly for a [MCVE]. You have not provide even a good description of the dataset being used. If you cannot provide a munged example that reproduces the problem because of business considerations. then .... hire a consultant with better skills than you have. You can then bind him/her with an NDA.

Comment: How are you checking for NAs?

Comment: I know that my data description is not very helpful, but I am not allowed to give any, and I know that the chance someone providing me with an answer is slim. However, I am just hoping someone recognizes the problem.

Comment: @rw2 like so colSums(is.na(data)). In data preprocessing I removed all entries with NAs so again, that can't be the problem. Moreover, when I am trying to fit a Random Forest with the RandomForest package, everything works fine, which is why I am thinking that the problem stems from trControl in Caret.